# Azure blob customerProvidedKey vs EncryptionPolicy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-security

I need to encrypt files uploaded to azure blob, so that no one logged to azure can see it. 
One of the solution is to use encryption with custom key. I found at least two ways of doing it but I can't tell what is the difference between them, maybe some of you will help me.

first solution is to create

```
BlobClientOptions options = new BlobClientOptions()
{
     CustomerProvidedKey = new CustomerProvidedKey(key)
};
```

and pass that option when creating `BlobServiceClient`

second one is to create

```
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
```

and use it when uploading file `blob.UploadFromStream(stream, stream.Length, null, options, null);`

I can't find any documentation telling the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CustomerProvidedKey** is used to encrypt data at azure server side(officially, it's called `encrypt at rest`), you can see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption) for more details. In short, when use this kind of encryption, during data uploading progress, the data is not encrypted. After the completion of upload, the data will be encrypted at azure server side with **CustomerProvidedKey**.

Note: **CustomerProvidedKey** is now [in preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption#customer-provided-keys-preview).

But for the second one by using **BlobEncryptionPolicy**, which is used to encrypt data at client side. When you use this kind of encryption, the data is encrypted before uploaded to azure.

Comment: after doing client side encrypt , does azure also do encrypt  when it received the data?